# Razor exit code block

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to avoid more nesting.
Is there any way to exit to the end of a `@{ //code }` block in Razor?
I tried the example below, but it simply ignores the rest of the view then.

```
@{
  if(Model.Products.Count == 0)
  {
    <p>No products were found</p>
    return;
  }

  // display products

} // I want to return to here

// Rest of the view
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, you could remove `return;` and put the product display code in an `else` block.

Comment: I know, that is what I am doing now, but I am trying to avoid nesting as much as possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**@helper**](http://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/173/the-difference-between-helpers-and-functions-in-webmatrix)

```
@helper DisplayProducts()
{
    if(Model.Products.Count == 0)
    {
        <p>No products were found</p>
        return;
    }

  // display products
}



 @DisplayProducts()
//Rest of the view
```